# R: plot with pdf as background

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I would like to plot in R using an existing pdf file as the background. The reason I don't want to use another format (png, jpg, gif), is that I don't want to lose *any* quality of the image in my (already existing) pdf file. Any recommendations? Many thanks!

Comment: you mean you have a pdf already that you want to plot on top of? If you just want to save your plot as a pdf, do `pdf("mypdf.pdf")`, then make your plot as normal, then `dev.off()`. You'll find it in your working directory. see `?pdf` for more info

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I have a pdf that I want to plot on top off :) I'll clarify that in my opening post, tnx.

Comment: take a look here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot tim riffe! I found the answer in that document:

First convert the pdf to ps. Then do the rest with the grImport package:

```
#convert the ps to xml:
PostScriptTrace("image.ps")

# store the xml info in RGML format (R Graphics Markup Language):
NLmap <- readPicture("image.ps.xml")

#plot the image
plot(etc...)
par(new=T)
plot(grid.picture(NLmap[-1]),etc...)
```

Comment: I converted pdf to ps by installing `ghostscript` and using `pdftops` in cmd.
After that, when I run `PostScriptTrace(p1.ps)`, I get the following error `Error in PostScriptTrace("p1.ps") : 
  status 127 in running command 'gswin32c.exe -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=C:\Users\urwa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpojNMJ4\filef98441515 -sstdout=p1.ps.xml capturep1.ps'` 
Any idea why.